# Sending JSON Data to printer in PDF format Angular

Tags: css, json, angular, page-break

I am getting JSON data from API, after getting that data i need to send that JSON data to print in pdf format. Please help me to solve this in Angular.

Reframing my question: I am now getting HTML data from API in an JSON format and I successfully rendered it on component but I am applying CSS for page-break-before is not working. Can anyone please help me out in it.
When I create in simple index.html file as a static data it is working but same with Angular component it is not working whether it is static or dynamic.

I tried

```
@media all {
.page-break { display: none; }
}
@media print {
.page-break { display: block; page-break-before: always; }
}
```

My HTML Code

```
<div class="page-break"></div>
<p>Date: 27/02/2020 </p>
<p>Sub: Request for ..............</p>
<p>WRT the BG number <b>123456789</b></p><br><br><br>
<p>Account number: 0000000000</p>
<p>Acccount Name: ABC</p>
<p>IFSC: ABC12456</p><br><br>
<p>Regards</p>

<div class="page-break"></div>
<p>Date: 27/02/2020 </p>
<p>Sub: Request for ..............</p>
<p>WRT the BG number <b>123456789</b></p><br><br><br>
<p>Account number: 0000000000</p>
<p>Acccount Name: ABC</p>
<p>IFSC: ABC12456</p><br><br>
<p>Regards</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is with [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) and [jsPdf](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF). First you convert your HTML to an image with html2canvas and then print the image with jsPdf

```
const input = document.getElementById('print-container');
html2canvas(input)
  .then((canvas) => {
    const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    const pdf = new jsPDF({
      orientation: 'landscape',
    });
    const imgProps = pdf.getImageProperties(imgData);
    const pdfWidth = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
    const pdfHeight = (imgProps.height * pdfWidth) / imgProps.width;
    pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 0, pdfWidth, pdfHeight);
    pdf.save('download.pdf');
  });
```

See this Stackblitz I made: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p1a7xn

Another way is to use jsPdf without html2canvas. Then you need to layout and style the pdf for yourself

Comment: I implemented it successfully created PDF but there is no content in it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to this library: http://pdfmake.org/#/

It's awesome!

Take a look to their playground here: http://pdfmake.org/playground.html

Basic example code:

```
const dd = {
    content: [
        'First paragraph',
        'Another paragraph, this time a little bit longer to make sure, this line will be divided into at least two lines'
    ]

}
```

This will create 2 lines in the PDF.

Their npm: **npm i pdfmake**

Comment: I have JSON data, is there any way to pass JSON data ?

Comment: Yes. you can pass data dynamically using this tool

Comment: Okay Thanks, i will check